# How to subscribe to change in database?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'd like to subscribe to changes in database and return them in SSE. Unfortunately, it looks like it doesn't listen to the changes. How to fix it?

service.ts

```
public async subscribeToBbChanges() {
    const stream = await this.bbSignalEntityRepository.createQueryBuilder().stream();


    return new Observable(observer => {
      stream.on('data', data => {
        observer.next({ data });
      });

    });
  }
```

controller.ts

```
@Sse()
  public handleBbSignalsChange(): any {
    return this.bbSignalsService.subscribeToBbChanges();
  }
```